# Complex SQL Server Database Query

Tags: sql-server

Previously I had only one table (I have more, ofc, but these are the ones I'm struggling with), which was the `UNIVERSITY` table.

I now want to create two more tables : `STATE` and `CITY`.

#### Table Attributes

```
UNIVERSITY: ID, NAME, SHORTNAME, FK_STATE, FK_CITY

STATE: ID, NAME, SHORTNAME

CITY : ID, NAME
```

#### Problem

I am parsing a excel sheet for the universities (including the city and state in which this university resides). Once I have all this information in memory, the hardest part comes.

How do I:

> Insert all Universities in the database,including its state and city, but querying the STATE and CITY databases for their IDs, to set the FK's of the university correctly.

Example:
Once I add a University named 'PUC-RIO', it is presented in 'RIO DE JANEIRO', (city) 'RIO DE JANEIRO' (state aswell). Adding the university itself is not a problem, but, how can I update its foreign key to the 'RIO DE JANEIRO' Key on state and city tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do this for each university:

```
INSERT INTO UNIVERSITY (..., FK_CITY, FK_STATE)
VALUES (..., (SELECT ID FROM CITY WHERE Name = @city), (SELECT ID FROM STATE WHERE Name = @state))
```

Comment: Seems like you are right, this is what i need.
I will give it a test

Answer (score 2):

While declaring the foreign key relationship you get a dialog box where in you specify the tables for the relationship

[image: Update rule]

By default the update rule is set to No Action .According to msdn articles there are several options which you can change while specifying the foreign key for a table

```
 Update Rule
```

Specify what occurs if a user tries to update a row with data that is involved in a foreign key relationship:

1.**No Action** An error message tells the user that the update is not allowed and the UPDATE is rolled back.

2. **Cascade** Updates all rows that contain data involved in the foreign key relationship. Do not specify CASCADE if the table will be included in a merge publication that uses logical records. For more information about logical records,
3. **Set Null** Sets the value to null if all foreign key columns for the table can accept null values. Applies to SQL Server 2005 only.
4. **Set Default**   Sets the value to the default value that is defined for the column if all foreign key columns for the table have defaults defined for them. Applies to SQL Server 2005 only.

You can explore these options which might help you in solving your problem .
Please refer [MSDN article documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177288%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't given the table definitions above, at least not in an automated way.  There needs to be something in the University table that ties it to the City and State tables.  If I understand you correctly, you need to temporarily include a CityName and StateName column in your University table, and then you can do a join between the name fields:

```
UPDATE U
    SET FK_CITY = C.ID
FROM UNIVERSITY AS U
    JOIN CITY AS C
        ON U.CITYNAME = C.NAME
```

Otherwise, you'll need to look up the FKs and manually add them when you add a new university. Also, it might be easier to have FK_State in the City table, that way you only need to add the city's ID to your university table.